# Why are people asking in present perfect?

Tags: discussion, questions, grammar

Most questions (especially those with low quality) that I see on Stack Overflow use present perfect when a simple past tense would work in describing what they did (I did this, I did that, ...). Is there a particular reason for that? Is it some kind of a programmer's slang?

**Example** For example, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16314178/revisions) (that I edited). In this example, the verb is not even past participle, and it looks as if the OP is mistaking the sequence `"I've"` to simply mean `"I"`. I saw so many of this sequence `"I've"` used in Stack Overflow. I am wondering what the cause of this is.

Comment: English is my 3rd Language, and I am Prefectly Present on S.O. since last 495, So you can see *Present Perfect* Tense in my sentences.

Comment: Visit : [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/?as=1) site  for these tense questions.

Comment: @exploringnet I don't think it is plain English. It is specific to programmers.

Comment: This does not have anything regarding programming....?

Comment: Although it now seems clear this is not the case, I have to admit that when I first read this I immediately thought it was written by some kind of incredibly esoteric troll....

Comment: @DavidJohnWelsh Why is that? I wrote this seriously. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @sawa Because it appeared you were asking why people were using a part of standard English in precisely the way it was intended to be used. *Why do some people use spades for digging? Is it some gardener's custom?* That a group of speakers (such as programmers) would have certain slang terms is obviously very likely, but the idea that *tense* or *aspect* would be used in that context seemed... overly silly. To me. For all I know, there are groups that do do this. As I said, it was just an initial gut reaction, and I see now that you meant it seriously. The example helped a lot to clarify.

Answer (score 6):

> The present perfect is a grammatical combination of the present tense and the perfect aspect, used to express a past event that has present consequences.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect)

By definition, questions which are asked on Stack Exchange are *currently* a problem and the user only describes the background to that problem. So I don't see why this wouldn't fit to be used.

Though, I also have to say that I *suck* at anything which has to do with tenses (both in my mother tongue German and in English). So I might not be that aware that there is a problem with that.

Comment: I don't know about other languages, but in German you'd use the (equivalent of the) present perfect tense all the time when describing things you did. Research papers written by Germans are full of "we have analyzed" et cetera.

Comment: I see it used in describing what they did like `I have done ...`. It doesn't add any information compared to `I did ...`.

Comment: @slhck German is different. German is under a general language-changing process of replacing past with perfect. That is a whole language change. Simple past tense itself is dying. In English, it is not.

Comment: @sawa Of course it doesn't add any information, but if it's closer to the mother tongue of the OP, then why would they write anything else? If they had a proper understanding of grammar in the first place, they maybe wouldn't write their posts in present perfect. You *do* know that a significant amount of low quality posts are from speakers whose mother tongue is not English?

Comment: @slhck A significant amount of low quality posts may be from non-natives as you wrote, but I didn't necessarily mean that. I found these expressions even on post by people who seem to be located in US.

Comment: @sawa: No, the correct use of tenses and/or grammar does not add anything "informational". But when *I* explain something I use "I have tried a and b" and answer direct questions with "Yes, I tried c". Now that I think about it "I have tried..." *really* shows me that there is still something going on and input from my end is requested, while "I tried" is a pure "ok" to me. But as slhck pointed out, that might be because of my mother tongue.

Comment: @sawa Fair enough. I'm not a native speaker, so I wouldn't know why that phenomenon also occurs in American English. I agree: it sounds wrong… but languages and their usage constantly change. Maybe ask on [English.SE]?

Comment: SulfurizedDemonbobby, slhck If it is influenced by the OP's native language like German, then that is understandable. I felt I only find this kind of expressions in stackoverflow, so I was curious whether it is just for programmers. Anyway, thanks for the opinions.